# MySQL Query with in is too much slow

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this MySQL query. It takes 6.3 seconds or more time.

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_wpds_tlds` WHERE 1 AND `id` IN (SELECT p.`tld_id` id FROM `wp_wpds_category_pivot` p, `wp_wpds_categories` c WHERE c.id=p.category_id AND `category` LIKE '%City%') ORDER BY `tld` ASC
```

Comment: what is explain? `explain SELECT * FROM wp_wpds_tlds WHERE 1 AND id IN (SELECT p.tld_id id FROM wp_wpds_category_pivot p, wp_wpds_categories c WHERE c.id=p.category_id AND category LIKE '%City%') ORDER BY tld ASC`

Answer (score -2):

You have to remove **1 AND** after WHERE:
SELECT * FROM `wp_wpds_tlds` **WHERE** `id IN (SELECT p.`tld_id`id FROM`wp_wpds_category_pivot`p,`wp_wpds_categories`c WHERE c.id=p.category_id AND`category`LIKE '%City%') ORDER BY`tld` ASC

Comment: time also depends on the number of records in the database

Comment: `1 AND` doesn't affect

Comment: how many rows you have in your database? it takes time because of large number of records

Comment: Yes, I tried without "1 AND"... Same result. it doesn't effect. It is required for dynamic queryl.